# Mongodb mongoose project only matching object element from array in document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is a document in my Meetings collection

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "meetings": [
    {
      "id": "00d505a2-5618-4ab1-aa31-7648fd93d41a",
      "time": "2022-08-08T22:25:00.000Z",
    },
    {
      "id": "37e81a14-b5fa-41ec-8a1a-6558af5d8212",
      "time": "2022-08-08T22:30:00.000Z",
    },
    {
      "id": "7f21bec2-fbff-4edb-b6ae-ed8ba57f385a",
      "time": "2022-08-08T23:15:00.000Z",
    },
  ]
}
```

I am trying to return only the meeting with `id: 00d505a2-5618-4ab1-aa31-7648fd93d41a`

I wrote a mongoose query like so:

```
const testProjection = Meetings.findOne(
  {
    _id: "1",
    "meetings.id": "00d505a2-5618-4ab1-aa31-7648fd93d41a",
  },
  {
    _id: 0,
    meetings: { $elemMatch: { id: "00d505a2-5618-4ab1-aa31-7648fd93d41a" } }
  }
);
```

and that returned an object like so:

```
{
  meetings: [
    {
      id: '00d505a2-5618-4ab1-aa31-7648fd93d41a',
      time: '2022-08-08T22:25:00.000Z',
    }
  ]
}
```

That is in the right direction but not exactly what I want.
Is it possible to return only

```
{
  id: '00d505a2-5618-4ab1-aa31-7648fd93d41a',
  time: '2022-08-08T22:25:00.000Z',
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is useful in your case. Use the aggregate:

```
Meetings.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$meetings"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "meetings.id": "00d505a2-5618-4ab1-aa31-7648fd93d41a"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$meetings"
    }
  }
])
```

This will return and array:

```
[
  {
    "id": "00d505a2-5618-4ab1-aa31-7648fd93d41a",
    "time": "2022-08-08T22:25:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

You can always add a `$limit` equal to 1 at the end of the pipeline, although the result will always be an array.

You can try how it works here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/hx5ebesf4_M